# how to avoid duplicate code when using an array of components

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have to create a GUI that consists of 10 buttons that are created in an array:

```
    public static final JButton[] buttons = new JButton[10];
```

Each button denotes a digit between 0 and 9. I want that whenever I press a button the temporary value I hold, will be multiplied by 10 and added to the value of the button (which is, ironically, it's index). Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { 

    if (e.getSource()==CalculatorGUI.buttons[0]) { 
        num=num*10;
        CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
    }
    if (e.getSource()==CalculatorGUI.buttons[1]) { 
        num=num*10+1;
        CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
    }
    if (e.getSource()==CalculatorGUI.buttons[2]) { 
        num=num*10+2;
        CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
    }
    if (e.getSource()==CalculatorGUI.buttons[3]) { 
        num=num*10+3;
        CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
    }
    if (e.getSource()==CalculatorGUI.buttons[4]) { 
        num=num*10+4;
        CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
    }....
```

The problem with this code is that the code duplicates itself with minor changes. I want to ask whether there is a better way to write this code in a shorter way without duplications (e.g. without a separate "if" for each button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for something more robust:

```
public class Example {

    public static final JButton[] BUTTONS = new JButton[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < BUTTONS.length; i++) {
            // initialize BUTTONS[i]
            BUTTONS[i].addActionListener(new MyActionListener(i));
        }
    }

    private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        int i;

        MyActionListener(int i) {

            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            num = num * 10 + i;
            CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
        }
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to check what the source component is.

Alternatively, you can rely on the source component:

```
public class Example {

    public static final JButton[] BUTTONS = new JButton[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < BUTTONS.length; i++) {
            // initialize BUTTONS[i]
            BUTTONS[i].setText(String.valueOf(i));
            BUTTONS[i].addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
        }
    }

    private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int i = Integer.parseInt(((JButton) e.getSource()).getText());
            num = num * 10 + i;
            CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
        }
    }
}
```

Or use whatever way to identify which button it is without iterating through all of them (like using `putClientProperty` and `getClientProperty`).

Also, `final` variables should be in uppercase according to the Java naming conventions.

Comment: One more question: Is there any method in Java that gets an element of an array and returns the index of this element in this array ?

Comment: I did what you wrote with getText(). I got a compilation error: 
"JButton cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @CrazySynthax Did you import it? I didn't paste a complete working code, just a replacement for yours.

Answer (score 0):

If your code works for you, you can reduce it:

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < CalculatorGUI.buttons.length; i++){
        if (e.getSource()==CalculatorGUI.buttons[i]) { 
            num=num*10 + i;
            CalculatorGUI.resultLabel.setText(Double.toString(num));
            return; //or break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a `return` as the final line in the `if` block to eliminate worthless iterations.